# Proposal: create the tags 'drone-ci' or 'drone-io', instead 'drone'

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

There's some confusion about the tag `drone`. There are a lot of questions about drones, the little machines, but those questions are tagged with the tag `drone`, about the continuous integration server https://drone.io.

Considering that the best-known meaning for the word `drone` is the machine, not the server, I propose to create a new tag that would be `drone-ci` or `drone-io`. And, of course, we need to change the description of the tag `drone` for its original meaning.

Looking forward for your comments.

Comment: This is something I've been struggling with (as the drone author). There are people using `drone` and also `drone.io`. Having things split across tags also makes it more difficult to monitor, and as a side note, more difficult to meet the minimum 500 question threshold for trying out stackoverflow documentation. If there is a preferred convention (`drone.io` vs `drone-io` vs `drone-ci`) I'm definitely open to setting a community standard as well as trying to get existing questions re-tagged